# How to start instance using URL in groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am tring to create a groovy script where i need to make a call to different master from another master to get some information. so i want to know if there is any possibility to start an instance on diffent master from another master in groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your trying to do but you can run a post-initialization-script that may help you

> You can create a Groovy script file $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy, or any
>   .groovy file in the directory $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script